# Capybara: page.execute_script() not working

Tags: selenium, drag-and-drop, capybara, rspec-rails, simulate

I am trying to simulate drag and drop using jquery.simulate library in rspec feature.The execute_script lines in spec are:

```
 page.execute_script("$('#slide_1').draggable();")
 page.evaluate_script("$('#slide_1').simulate('drag', {dragTarget: '#library_swap', interpolation: {stepWidth: 10, stepDelay: 300 }});")
 page.evaluate_script("$('#slide_1').simulate('drop');")
```

If I run the lines inside the execute script over chrome console,its working fine(drag-drop simulation works),but not working with execute_script

Comment: Do you get any errors, or does it just not do what you expect? Is there a reason you’re using `evaluate_script` for the second and third statements?

Comment: @ThomasWalpole No I haven't received any error but the script is not executing. I used execute_script before using evaluate script but both of these not working.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're not getting any errors, the JS code you're passing to `execute_script` is actually being executed.  Since you're not seeing the behavior you expect the most likely explanation is that you're executing the JS before the element is actually on the page, which would then just silently do nothing.  The one thing that confuses me about the code is why you're calling `draggable` on the `#slide_1` element since I would assume that had already been called in your app.  Anyway - add an expectation before your `execute_script` calls to make sure the element is actually on the page

```
expect(page).to have_css('#slide_1')
execute_script("$('#slide_1')...
```

Also note, there shouldn't be any reason you need to use three different `execute_script` calls for this, you could just combine them all into one.  In recent versions of Capybara you can also DRY up the commands by not specifying the selector again and instead passing the element to execute_script

```
slider = page.find(:css, '#slide_1')
execute_script("$(arguments[0]). ...    ", slider)
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I resolved the issue by adding a sleep after second line. Actually the script was executing but didn't seem to be working on UI.